# Managing signals within a testbench module in SystemC

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, systemc, test-bench

I'm trying to simulate in SystemC a module with a CABA (Cycle Accurate / Bit Accurate) model which adds two numbers. It has the following signals:

**Module `addition_CABA`**

- `a`: Input number for the addition.
- `b`: Input number for the addition.
- `clk`: Clock input.
- `valid`: Input signal which changes to 1 when the inputs `a` and `b` are available.
- `result`: Output signal containing the result of `a` + `b`.
- `ready`: Output signal which changes to 1 when `result` is ready.

In order to test if the result from this module is right I have created a `testbench` module which has the following signals:

**Module `testbench`**

- `result_tb`: Input signal which receives the result signal from `addition_CABA` module.
- `ready_tb`: Input signal which receives the ready signal from `addition_CABA` module.
- `clk_tb`: Clock input signal. It's the same for both modules.
- `rst_tb`: Reset input signal. It's the same for both modules.
- `a_tb`: Output signal which sends the number a to `addition_CABA` module.
- `b_tb`: Output signal which sends the number b to `addition_CABA` module.
- `valid_tb`: Output signal which sends the valid signal to `addition_CABA` module.

The test I'm doing is as follows:

- Within the module `testbench` a pair of random numbers is generated to give values to `a` and `b`.
- The module calcules the result after some clock cycles.
- The testbench directly does the addition operation and compares it with the one resulting from the module.
- These actions are within a loop which repeats five times.

The problem I'm having is that when I run the simulation `testbench` gives the right result, and `addition_CABA` shows the result but some clock cycles later, so the comparison is between two different numbers. In addition, when the program ends I have a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` message. What I'm trying to figure it out is how to indicate `testbench` to wait until the result is ready (with signal `ready_tb`) so it can do the comparison with the right number. I have tried with a `while(!ready_tb.read()) wait();` condition just before starting the test, but when doing this the program ends and the simulation never starts.

In the `main.cpp` file I'm just doing the connections between modules, generating the clock and setting the `rst` signal to `0`. Below is my code:

**addition_CABA.h**

```
#include <systemc.h>
//Module which adds two numbers
SC_MODULE(addition_CABA){
    sc_in< sc_uint<8> > a;
    sc_in< sc_uint<8> > b;
    sc_in<bool> clk;
    sc_in<bool> valid;
    sc_in<bool> rst;
    sc_out<bool> ready;
    sc_out< sc_uint<8> > result;

    int addcaba(int a, int b){
        int c;
        c = a+b;
        wait(3);
        return c;
    }

    void loop();

    SC_CTOR(addition_CABA){
        SC_CTHREAD(loop, clk.pos());
        async_reset_signal_is(rst, true);
    }

};
```

**addition_CABA.cpp**

```
void addition_CABA::loop(){

    ready.write(0);
    result.write(0);

    if(rst){
        ready.write(0);
        result.write(0);
    }   

    else{

        while(1){
            while (!valid.read()) wait();

            result.write(addcaba(a.read(),b.read()));
            ready.write(1);

            wait();
            ready.write(0);
        }

    }
}
```

**testbench.h**

```
#include <systemc.h>

SC_MODULE(testbench){

    sc_in< sc_uint<8> > result_tb;
    sc_in<bool> ready_tb;
    sc_in<bool> clk_tb;
    sc_in<bool> rst_tb;

    sc_out< sc_uint<8> > a_tb;
    sc_out< sc_uint<8> > b_tb;
    sc_out<bool> valid_tb;

    void test();

    SC_CTOR(testbench){
        SC_CTHREAD(test, clk_tb.pos());
        async_reset_signal_is(rst_tb, true);
    }   

};
```

**testbench.cpp**

```
void testbench::test(){

    uint8_t c = 0;
    int k = 0;

    if (rst_tb){
        c = 0;
        k = 0;
        cout << "\nReset on!\n" << endl;
    }

    else{
        //while(!ready_tb.read()) wait(); //when using this condition the simulation never starts
            while(k < 5){
                a_tb.write( (1 + rand() % (128-1)) );
                b_tb.write( (1 + rand() % (128-1)) );

                valid_tb.write(1);
                sc_start(10, SC_NS);

                valid_tb.write(0);
                sc_start(10, SC_NS);

                cout << "\nTest number " << k+1 << endl;
                cout << "\ta = " << a_tb.read() << " and b = " << b_tb.read() << endl;
                cout << "\tAddition of " << a_tb.read() << " and " << b_tb.read();
                cout << " = " << result_tb.read() << endl;

                c = a_tb.read() + b_tb.read();

                if ( result_tb.read() != c ){
                    cout << "Real result = " << a_tb.read() + b_tb.read();
                    cout << " and result with module = " << result_tb.read() << endl;  
                    cout << "Wrong result\n" << endl;
                    //  exit(1);
                }

                else cout << "Result OK\n" << endl;
                k++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root causes of the problem were the following ones:

1. The simulation time in `main.cpp` function was too short (10 ns, I modified to 500 ns).
2. As the test function in the testbench module is an `SC_CTHREAD`, it must be within an infinite loop. The previous implementation was completely wrong and I think this was also the root cause of the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` message.

In addition, the loop which repeats the test five times is not necessary as the number of iterations is related to the simulation time (set in the `main.cpp` function). Below is the code for `testbench.cpp` corrected:

```
void testbench::test(){

    uint8_t c = 0;
    int k = 0;

    if (rst_tb){
        c = 0;
        k = 0;
        cout << "\nReset on!\n" << endl;
    }

    else{
        while(1){   
                a_tb.write( (1 + rand() % (128-1)) );
                b_tb.write( (1 + rand() % (128-1)) );

                valid_tb.write(1);
                wait();
                valid_tb.write(0);
                wait();

                while(!ready_tb.read()) wait();//This condition waits until ready_tb = true to continue the simulation

                cout << "\nTest number " << k+1 << endl;
                cout << "\ta = " << a_tb.read() << " and b = " << b_tb.read() << endl;
                cout << "\tAddition of " << a_tb.read() << " and " << b_tb.read();
                cout << " = " << result_tb.read() << endl;

                c = a_tb.read() + b_tb.read();

                if ( result_tb.read() != c ){
                    cout << "Real result = " << a_tb.read() + b_tb.read();
                    cout << " and result with module = " << result_tb.read() << endl;  
                    cout << "Wrong result\n" << endl;
                    exit(1);
                }

                else cout << "Result OK\n" << endl;

                k++;
        }   
    }
}
```